# Sencha Touch 2, get the name of the view from using get component

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

Inside my Sencha Touch controller, I am selecting my views, using refs:

config: {

```
refs: {
    HomeView: 'HomeView',
    LoginView: 'LoginView',
    ProductsView: 'ProductsView',
    TestViewTwo: 'TestViewTwo'
}
```

}

I have the routes:

```
routes: {
    '': 'home',
    'home' : 'home',
    'login' : 'login',
    'products' : 'products',
    'products/:id': 'product',
    'testingtwo' : 'testingtwo'
}
```

And, when the user gets on a certain route, I do the following check:

> see if the view exists, if not create it, and add it to the viewport

```
home: function () {

    console.log('TestApp.controller.Router home function');

    var comp = this.getHomeView();

    // How can I get the view name from "comp", to avoid manually typing the name of the new view:
    newView = 'TestApp.view.HomeView';  // i want to avoid this.

    // the pseudo code should be:
    newView = comp.getViewName;


    if (comp === undefined) comp = Ext.create(newView);

    this.changeView(comp);
}
```

**How can I get the view name from "comp", to avoid manually typing the name of the new view?**

I have explained it better in the code above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Ext.ClassManager.getClass(component);`